# What is the correct configuration declarations for -servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am learning how to work with @MVC and right now I am confused with the configuration files "...-servlet.xml" and "applicationContext.xml". The following *do work* and I would appreciate if you could point out what is redundant or misplaced. For example, how can I avoid duplicating the Controller package scanning?

mrpomario-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="mrpomario.springcore.mvc.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="mrpomario.springcore.mvc.controller, mrpomario.springcore.mvc.dao, mrpomario.springcore.mvc.service"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="/WEB-INF/mvc-db.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>mrpomario/springcore/mvc/domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>MrPomario</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mrpomario</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mrpomario</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rationale:
spring-config.xml -> sees beans in -> applicationContext.xml BUT NOT VICE-VERSA.

When I moved the Controller scanning into spring-confing.xml it still did not work. What was preventing it from functioning was that I kept in the applicationContext.xml the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>    

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver"/>
```

These (in applicationContext.xml) did not scan my Controller's @RequestMappings because they were defined in the spring-config.xml and therefore could not be seen.

Answer (score 0):

applicationContext will be shared between different spring servlets if they are present (commonly there is only one).

To avoid duplication just remove from one of the files.

If it causes problems, your web-inf/web.xml may not be correctly set up. Its needs to reference the correct files to configure the context.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mrpomario</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mrpomario-servlet.xml.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Comment: agreed; I would remove it from the applicationContext.xml (leaving it only in the -servlet.xml). THOUGH, by doing so my mappings stop working (No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [feed/list]). Then, how to fix this?

Comment: I believe web-inf/web.xml is referencing mrpomario-servlet.xml correctly. I just placed it in my question.

Comment: @Pomario updated answer, assumed your config file was in web-inf directory

Comment: yes, it is in web-inf. I see what you mean, but in the book Spring by Example it says: "By default, a look is made for a file by joining the servlet name with -servlet.xml as the file name." So, I would expect that the framework would get mrpomario (from the <servlet-name>) and derive the file name mrpomario-servlet.xml and load it automatically. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No you are not missing anything, there may be another issue ... try it first.Maybe they changed bedefault behaviour with a different version.

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks for all your time and help NimChimpsky, it's been really appreciated!